# Dynamically Register Generic Signalr Hub Routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket, routes, signalr

I have a multi-web-socket architecture where my hubs piggy back my rest service. 
 Event are thrown from my crud methods.  My services are registered dynamically my startup looks something like this:

```
var messageHubConfig = new DynamicHubServicConfiguration<Message, MessageDTO>();

//Registers service with a hub
restConfiguration.RegisterRestService(typeof(IMessageDTOService), 
                                         typeof(MessageDTOService), 
                                         messageHubConfig);
```

I would like to generically register my hub routes at the same time I register my services based off of the generic parameter being used.  Currently I'm manually registering routes like so:

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<CRUDServiceHubBase<MessageDTO>>("/messages");
});
```

I would like to register a conventions for my dynamically registered hubs, the only way I can think of how to do it currently would be

```
//this is pseudo coded
public void RegisterServiceHubConvention(IServicesProvder services, IApplicationBuilder app)
{
     //Get all the services
     var crudServices = services.GetServices(typeof(CRUDServiceHubBase<>))
     var serviceMap = MapGenericParameterToHubType(crudServices);
     var hubMapAction = BuildHubRoutesActionFromParameterTypeName(serviceMap);
    hubMapAction(app);
}
```

Why isn't signalr configured using services?

I would prefer not to have to build my service provider in the in the AppServices, or manually write conventions this way.  Is there a more user-friendly approach for creating Hub Routes?